# Assembly x86 imul and div aren't doing what I expect

Tags: assembly, x86

When I go to divide, it gives me some out of this world answers. This works:

```
mov ax, 11
mov bl, 37
div bl
mov [bAns16], ah
```

And will give me the correct remainder of 11. But as soon as I switch those numbers to variables, the whole thing breaks:

```
mov ax, [bNum1]
mov bl, [bNum4]
div bl
mov [bAns16], ah


;bNum1 = 11
;bNum4 = 37
```

The answer should be 0 with a remainder of 11. But the answer ends up 104 and with a remainder of 3 somehow.

Moreover, I'm having issues with using imul - makes no sense at all. Same as with div:

```
mov ax, 33
mov bx, -17
imul ax, bx
mov [wAns15], ax
```

Will give me the correct answer, but won't as soon as I put variables in there:

```
mov ax, [bNum5]
mov bx, [bNum6]
imul ax, bx
mov [wAns15], ax

;bNum5 = 33
;bNum6 = -17
```

So it should equal -561, but gives me -32049 instead consistently.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

EDIT:

Here are the number declarations:

```
bNum1       db  11
bNum2       db  15
bNum3       db  26
bNum4       db  37
bNum5       db  33
bNum6       db  -17
bNum7       db  -29
bNum8       db  -40
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are declaring all `bNum`s using `DB` or `DW`? It seems to me that you are using constants. In that case `mov ax, [bNum1]` is like `mov ax, [11]` and causes the problem.

Comment: All are declared with DB and initialized with their values. Don't get what you mean by the last part. How would the mov cause issues when I've moved these variables many times before with no issue?

Comment: Show us the actual definitions for `bNum5` and `bNum6`.  Descriptions are what you think you are declaring and may not be what you are actually declaring.

Comment: I edited it to include the declarations.

Comment: You should use `DW` for `bNum1`, `bNum5` and `bNum6`, as they are `word` not `byte`.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of [8086 assembly on DOSBox: Bug with idiv instruction?](//stackoverflow.com/a/43575674)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer should be 0 with a remainder of 11. But the answer ends up 104 and with a remainder of 3 somehow.

This means that `AX` contained the value `0x0F0B` instead of `0x000B` before the `div` instruction.

W. Chang's comment implies the reason for this:

Unlike higher-level programming languages (such as C), assembly language is there to tell the CPU *directly* what to do.

Therefore it is up to the programmer to ensure that data types are used correctly.

Your "variable" `bNum1` is one byte long. This would be a variable of the type `unsigned char` in C programming language.

However, the instruction `mov ax, [bNum1]` will access a two-byte value in memory. This equals the data type `unsigned short` in C.

This instruction will interpret the **two** bytes stored at the address `bNum1` and the address following that address as one 16-bit number.

The byte at address `bNum1` is 11 and the byte at the address following that address (`bNum2`) is 15; these two bytes will be interpreted as `0xF0B`.

**What to do**

W. Chang already recommended to use `dw` instead of `db`.

In C programming language this would be changing the data type of the variable `bNum1` from `unsigned char` to `unsigned short`.

However, you might not want to change the data type.

In this case you will need to convert an 8-bit number to a 16-bit number:

For *unsigned* numbers this is simply done by setting the high 8 bits to zero.

For *signed* numbers the x86 CPUs have instructions named `cbw` (8 to 16 bits) and `cwd` (16 to 32 bits). Unfortunately, this only works with the `AX` register.

The following examples show how a 8-bit number in `AL` is converted to a 16-bit number in `AX`:

Unsigned:

```
mov al, [bNum1]
mov ah, 0
```

Signed:

```
; You want to load bNum6 to BX ...
mov al, [bNum6]
cbw
mov bx, ax
; ... and bNum5 to AX
mov al, [bNum5]
cbw
```

Comment: You only need to zero- or sign-extend *one* of the inputs for `div`, and use 8-bit operand size like the OP's already doing.  (In the divisor can just be a memory source operand).  And for multiply, you might consider using widening `mul` or `imul` here to do 8x8 -> 16-bit multiply instead of manually sign-extending first (especially if you don't have 386 `movsx` or `movzx` instructions).  `imul r8, r/m8` doesn't exist but `mul r/m8` does.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answer was very helpful! This was a good addition to Chang's answer. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

`AX` and `BX` are 16-bit registers. `mov ax, [bNum1]` will read 16 bits (two bytes) from `bNum1`. But since `[bNum1]` (`0x0B`) is only one byte, it will also read `[bNum2]` (`0x0F`) as the high byte. So after `mov ax, [bNum1]` `AX` is not `11`, but `3851` (`0x0F0B`).

Comment: Thanks! That solved it. Because this was given to us and I shouldn't change it, I instead just changed ah to 0 before the division. However, can I get some more insight? How come when doing moving bNum1 into ax it'll take two bytes? Can't it see that the variable is only one byte? Can you explain why mov al, [bNum1] gives me an error when I run it (arithmetic error it says)? It goes away when I also full ah with 0. Thanks and sorry for the ton of questions.

Comment: @zapshe: "Can't it see that the variable is only one byte?" It depends on which assembler you're using. Some (like NASM and YASM) in fact cannot see that, because a label, to them, is just a memory address. They don't have a concept of the size of a "variable". And `mov al, [bNum1]` needs to be paired with `mov ah, 0` lest ah remain uninitialised, which could have it at a very high value. (You can also do `xor ax, ax` zeroing then a `mov al, ...` write.)